# Is it possible to crop/create thumbnails using apache POI

Tags: java, image-processing, apache-poi

I wanted o know whether it's possible to compress a given image to a predefined size in apache POI.
Say I have an input image of 500X500, and I want to convert to a thumbnail size (40X40), can I do it in apache POI?

if not, does java library provide any image processing capabilities?

Right now, I was able to embed images using apache POI, but I have no control over forcing the image to be with in a certain cell size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Picture interface in POI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize%28double%29) has resize methods as in the Javadocs

> void resize(double scale)
>
> Parameters:
>
> scale - the amount by which image dimensions are multiplied relative
>   to the original size. resize(1.0) sets the original size, resize(0.5)
>   resize to 50% of the original, resize(2.0) resizes to 200% of the
>   original.

Use either the `HSSFPicture` or `XSSFPicture` implementations

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache POI is designed to deal with Microsoft Documents, I wouldn't say it isn't possible.

A quick look through the Java Doc and nothing jumps out at me.

[Image resizing](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) is a fun exercise with lots of trade offs and options.